# ¿Como hacer Drag&Drop con Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-2015, tkinter

[image: GUI hecho con Tkinter]

Necesito poder arrastrar y despues soltar los botones hacia el cuadro blanco.
¿O me recomendarían usar IronPython con XAMP?

Acepto sugerencias, libros, videos. Gracias

Comment: Hola HiperEmmanuel. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Podrías mostrar qué intentaste hasta ahora? Quizás te sea útil realizar el [tour] y leer [ask] para entender las respuestas con recomendaciones son algo que se busca evitar en el sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque muy mal documentado, Tkinter tiene [soporte para *"D&D"*](https://github.com/akheron/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/dnd.py), siempre y cuando se haga dentro de la misma aplicación (como parece ser tu caso). Es experimental y será reemplazado por Tk DND, por lo que no lo usaría en producción.